# Value within input not binding in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have an *ngFor that loops through all my Friends. Within the for I have an input box that stores the name of the friend. I would like to store the value of the update name of the friend when I click a button, but this is not working as expected:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
  <div *ngFor="let friend of friends">
    <input type="text" [value]="friend.name">
    <button (click)="save(friend)" type="submit">save</button>
  </div>`,
  providers: []
})
export class App {
  friends: Friend[] = new Array(new Friend("Alice"), new Friend("Bob"));

  save(friend: Friend) {
    console.log(friend.name);
  }
}

export class Friend {
  constructor(public name: string) {}
}
```

The expectation is that the save method would be called with a friend object that contains the new value for the name. But it's just passing the old name.

I feel like I'm missing something fundamental with the way Angular2 works.

**Plunkr**: http://plnkr.co/edit/blYzEW0JufOcPwIwzoWQ?p=preview

Comment: its passing the old name because you're passing the old name into the save method.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to handle the change event - when it changes assign `friend.name`:

```
<input type="text" (change)='friend.name=$event.target.value' [value]="friend.name">
```

Or setup two-way data binding with `ngModel`:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="friend.name">
```

Demp Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/49tWBSyZAIToreQKyOh6?p=preview