# Object is possibly 'null

Tags: angular, typescript

I am learning angular and I am new to it I don't know why but I am facing this error `Object is possibly 'null'`, this is my code:

component.html

```
<input [value]="email" (keyup.enter)="email = $event.target.value; onKeyUp()"/>
```

component.ts

```
 email: string = "me@example.com"

 onKeyUp(){
     console.log(this.email)
 }
```

I tried using this also but it throws a new error `tsconfig.json`
`"strictNullChecks": false,`

Comment: What is the reason for using `keyUp`, would using `[(ngModel)]="email"` be an option? https://angular.io/api/forms/NgModel

Comment: <input [value]="email"  [(ngModel)]="email" /> this is working with two way biding data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Value within input not binding in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289665/value-within-input-not-binding-in-angular-2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**With the [value] binding**

You could possibly check to use the [value] binding with a proper configuration on the *change* input event

```
<input type="text" (change)='email=$event.target.value' [value]="email">
```

that will be updating the controller without needing the *onKeyUp* method in the controller.

**With the [(ngModel)] binding**

But the probably most common way to achieve this is to use the *ngModel* two-way data binding. So you will be also obtaining a better consistency of your `email` property on the *controller* and on the *view* too.

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="email">
```

To be able to use this on your code, you will need to set up the `FormsModule` on your `app.module.ts`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
// ...
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; // <---


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule // <---
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: thankYou bro first method is not working ' [value] ' but two way binding is working