# Angular 15 binding issue with template

Tags: angular

Using Angular 15 we face the following binding problem...

```
<ng-template #editDeal let-xdossier="thisDeal">
    <button [cModalToggle]="editDealModal.id" cButton>...</button>
    
    <c-modal #editDealModal id={{xdossier.id}} scrollable size="xl" >
        <c-modal-body>
            <label cLabel for="customerId">Customer Id</label>
            <input [(value)]="xdossier.customerId" type="text"  />

        </c-modal-body>
        <c-modal-footer>
            <button cButton color="primary" (click)="saveDeal(xdossier)">Save</button>
        </c-modal-footer>
    </c-modal>

</ng-template>
```

When we call **saveDeal**, we find with regret that customerId is not updated with user's input.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Might need to post more info to receive any helpful suggestions,
Maybe post the controller code.

Comment: Thanks, I found my answer in another post, just after publishing it -not before! It was just a syntax problem, not value={{..}}, not [ngModel]=... but ([ngModel]) did what we intended to do.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer in this post...

[Value within input not binding in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42289665/value-within-input-not-binding-in-angular-2)

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="xdossier.customerId"  />
```